# matplotlib.pyplot hist2d using hammer projection

Tags: matplotlib, histogram, projection

**Is it possible to use the 'hammer' (or any other) projection with a hist2d in matplotlib.pyplot?**

I know that it's fairly easy with a scatter plot using e.g. this code (I use a custom version of hammer that has been previously registered using register_projection('custom_hammer')):

```
plt.subplot(111, projection='custom_hammer')
plt.scatter(GalLon, GalLat, color='red')
```

Here, GalLon and GalLat are numpy arrays (1D). This is creating a nice scatter plot. Now I want to histogram the data, but keep the projection:

```
plt.subplot(111, projection='custom_hammer')
plt.hist2d(GalLon, GalLat, bins=[36, 18], norm=LogNorm())
```

This is creating an empty skymap and the following error:

```
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/image.py:156: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  sx = dxintv/viewlim.width
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/image.py:172: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  sx = dxintv/viewlim.width
```